# How to Have a COUNTIF Function dependent on the dates of the same row in R

Tags: r

My main problem is figuring out a way to count the number of days a particular item was sold. For example, if I have the following data frame, I would like to count the number of days in which item `A` or `B` were sold, i.e., item `A` was only sold on one day during our sample, and item `B` was sold 3 times, however only sold on 2 different days. My goal would be to have a function that outputs the number of days in which item was sold, here being `(A,B)=(1, 2)`.

```
row      item_name   date
 1       A           2016-03-04 3:49
 2       B           2016-05-31 16:15
 3       B           2016-05-31 16:35
 4       B           2016-06-08 16:05
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(item_name) %>% summarise(n_distinct(as.Date(date)))
```